# cURL fails when ping success on macos

Tags: macos, curl

It happens on my macbook(OSX 10.15.4).
I'm not fully understanding this problem, and it doesn't happen in other PC(OSX 10.15.4), iTerm.
Both were done with full disk access on terminal, and same network.

1. ping / dig works
2. curl doesn't works(-4 -6 both not work)
3. browser works normally.
4. flushed dns and wifi, but not fixed.

Response:

```
$ curl -v google.com
*   Trying 172.217.14.206...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 172.217.14.206: Operation not permitted
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server

$ dig google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 59652
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     121 IN  A   172.217.14.206

;; Query time: 244 msec
;; SERVER: 64.59.144.92#53(64.59.144.92)
;; WHEN: Tue May 19 14:36:01 PDT 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55

$ ping 172.217.14.206
PING 172.217.14.206 (172.217.14.206): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.14.206: icmp_seq=0 ttl=56 time=18.432 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.14.206: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=169.908 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.14.206: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=19.552 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.14.206: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=156.050 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.14.206: icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=19.996 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.14.206: icmp_seq=5 ttl=56 time=291.853 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.14.206: icmp_seq=6 ttl=56 time=25.486 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.14.206: icmp_seq=7 ttl=56 time=20.511 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.14.206: icmp_seq=8 ttl=56 time=21.455 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.14.206: icmp_seq=9 ttl=56 time=20.323 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.14.206: icmp_seq=10 ttl=56 time=20.087 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.14.206: icmp_seq=11 ttl=56 time=18.373 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.14.206: icmp_seq=12 ttl=56 time=15.993 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.14.206: icmp_seq=13 ttl=56 time=17.147 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.14.206: icmp_seq=14 ttl=56 time=19.605 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.14.206: icmp_seq=15 ttl=56 time=19.699 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.14.206: icmp_seq=16 ttl=56 time=35.372 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.14.206: icmp_seq=17 ttl=56 time=30.903 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.14.206: icmp_seq=18 ttl=56 time=23.162 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.14.206: icmp_seq=19 ttl=56 time=19.313 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.14.206: icmp_seq=20 ttl=56 time=17.620 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.14.206: icmp_seq=21 ttl=56 time=20.619 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.14.206: icmp_seq=22 ttl=56 time=23.571 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.14.206: icmp_seq=23 ttl=56 time=15.806 ms
```

- nc commands output

```
$ dig www.google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> www.google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 5970
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.com.     85  IN  A   172.217.14.228

;; Query time: 31 msec
;; SERVER: 64.59.144.92#53(64.59.144.92)
;; WHEN: Thu May 21 14:59:11 PDT 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 59


$ nc -z -v 172.217.14.228 80
Connection to 172.217.14.228 port 80 [tcp/http] succeeded!

$ nc -z -v 172.217.14.228 443
Connection to 172.217.14.228 port 443 [tcp/https] succeeded!
```

- telnet

```
$ telnet 172.217.14.228
Trying 172.217.14.228...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Operation timed out
```

- ssh

```
$ ssh git@github.com
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi XXXXX! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Connection to github.com closed.
```

Comment: Operation not permitted seems very weird, does curl give the same output with sudo?

Comment: Could be firewall allowing ICMP but not TCP. does telnet work?

Comment: @jac Yeap, it returns same response.

Comment: @root telnet failed with "Operation timed out"
BTW, nc command works! it super confuse me...

Comment: Can you add the nc and telnet commands you used, and their output? I'm assuming you used the right ports.

Comment: @root I put on the post. ssh works also.

Comment: You used the wrong telnet port, but the nc port is right. the issue doesn't reproduce for me, are you able to reproduce it from another machine? what is the version of curl? can you link to the output of `dtruss -a curl -v google.com`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happened because AV software blocked the curl. Thank you all.